# LotusNotes using Java - How to Change DesignTemplateName

Tags: java, lotus

I would like to change the DesignTemplateName in lotus notes using Java.

```
import lotus.domino.*;
public class AccessDomino {
    Session session = NotesFactory.createSession("AAAAA","BBBBBB","CCCCCCC");
    Database db = session.getDatabase(null, "DDD/EEE.nsf");
System.out.println(db.getDesignTemplateName());
```

That is how i can print the DesignTemplateName.  How can I change it and save it?

Answer (score 1):

The design template name is stored in the Icon. And there it is stored in the $title Field. A little bit crazy I know.

You can access the icon with this code:

```
NoteCollection nc = db.createNoteCollection(false);
nc.setSelectIcon(true);
nc.buildCollection();

String noteid = nc.getFirstNoteID();
Document icon = db.getDocumentByID(noteid);
```

Now you can change the TemplateName with this:

```
icon.replaceItemValue("$Title", db.getTitle() + "\n#2" + "newTemplate");
icon.save(true);
```

Dont forget, that the "Designer Task" has to run later from the server console (or better nightly scheduled) to really replace the design.

```
load design -f myFolder\myDB.nsf
```